# Get list Internet Access Point programmatically on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-privateapi

How to get list Internet Access Point programmatically on iOS?

Are there any public or private API's to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**This info was applicable to iOS 7 and most likely not applicable to newer iOS versions.**

I think it make sense to disassemble and look in two places:

a) CoreTelephony framework.

It has API's like:

CTServerConnectionGetAttachAPNSetttings

Also it has a key for some function kCTDeviceManagementAPNList. I am not sure where should it be passed, but it looks like it's used to retreive a list of APN's

b) ManagedConfiguration framework

You can set APN through using configuration profile. So, you probably can find in there API's which are used to store/retreive them.

As AlexWien correctly pointed out. Both of these things are private API's. I am not aware of public API's which can get APN's info.

Comment: You should note that this is a private API

Comment: There is no such method "CTServerConnectionGetAttachAPNSetttings" also no keyword like APN. can you please help me to create access point in ios. what API contains those information.

Comment: @Rajesh See my comment which I added (first line).